# Insert data using Mongodb Rest Interface

Tags: mongodb

i am using mongodb rest interface to get data from server.
but anyone have idea how to insert data to particular collection using Rest interface.

Comment: You would write one. MongoDB's built in stuff is intended for non-production/administrative purposes.

Comment: why downvote?, please comment for what reason down vote casted .

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the built-in REST-interface then there is no support for inserting new documents. It's stated in [their documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/).

> The mongod process includes a simple REST interface, with no support for insert/update/remove operations, as a convenience – it is generally used for monitoring/alerting scripts or administrative tasks.